# How to solve Installation failed due to invalid APK file?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I'm trying to build Dolphin Player, but I got his error:

```
[2012-09-21 09:46:23 - DolphinPlayer] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
[2012-09-21 09:46:23 - DolphinPlayer] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-09-21 09:46:23 - DolphinPlayer] Launch canceled!


09-21 09:32:15.460: W/PackageParser(52): Unknown element under <application>: intent-filter at /data/app/vmdl30455.tmp Binary XML file line #31
09-21 09:32:17.360: E/PackageManager(52): Package com.broov.player has mismatched uid: 10031 on disk, 10035 in settings
09-21 09:32:17.370: I/PackageManager(52): /data/app/vmdl30455.tmp changed; unpacking
09-21 09:32:17.390: W/PackageManager(52): Native ABI mismatch from package file
09-21 09:32:17.400: W/PackageManager(52): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.broov.player.apk
09-21 09:32:17.460: D/AndroidRuntime(833): Shutting down VM
09-21 09:32:17.460: D/dalvikvm(833): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit
09-21 09:32:17.460: D/dalvikvm(833): DestroyJavaVM shutting VM down
09-21 09:32:17.460: D/dalvikvm(833): HeapWorker thread shutting down
09-21 09:32:17.460: D/dalvikvm(833): HeapWorker thread has shut down
09-21 09:32:17.470: D/jdwp(833): JDWP shutting down net...
09-21 09:32:17.470: I/dalvikvm(833): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
09-21 09:32:17.480: D/dalvikvm(833): VM cleaning up
09-21 09:32:17.480: E/AndroidRuntime(833): ERROR: thread attach failed
09-21 09:32:17.490: D/dalvikvm(833): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 631172 of 5242880 (12%)
09-21 09:32:17.669: D/dalvikvm(52): GC freed 8681 objects / 526608 bytes in 239ms
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Comment: some links to similar problems: (http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2009/05/25/android-fix-package-uid-mismatches/) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431759/package-xyz-has-mismatched-uid-10044-on-disk-10045-in-settings) (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/enDoyYlyHik) the last link might be the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be two cases.

1. AndroidManifest.xml
2. Included .jar file also may be the cause of this problem.

for more information take a look

[Eclipse installation failed due to invalid APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998101/eclipse-installation-failed-due-to-invalid-apk-file)

OR

[Installation failed due to invalid APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230757/installation-failed-due-to-invalid-apk-file)

OR

[Installation failed due to invalid APK file! - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530097/installation-failed-due-to-invalid-apk-file-android)

OR

[Installation failed - invalid apk file - android_opencv_library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760027/installation-failed-invalid-apk-file-android-opencv-library)

Comment: uninstalling the app from the emulator and reinstalling did the trick for me

Answer (score 3):

It looks like in your AndroidManifest.xml file something has gone wrong. An intent-filter in the wrong place maybe? I think it need to be within an <activity> tag, not within the <application> tag.

Answer (score 3):

I have same error when I am running the application then **I deleted the bin folder** **and cleaned project** and run again, It is again created bin folder and run without any errors.

Comment: Is there any rationale behind that action? I mean, did you guess what to do?

Comment: just open the application in android studio and inside the app we have bin folder you can remove that, because it will automatically created when we give build.For me it works

Answer (score 2):

Build > Rebuild Project.. 
Fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

- **step 1**: In my case, I deleted the **app-debug.apk** in ...\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug    folder.
- **step 2**: Then run again.
  That's work for me.

**Good luck.Never Give up!!!**